# Returning a list as a data structure contract

Tags: c, data-structures, shared-libraries

I am working on a shared library (aka dll) implementation that can be consumed by other C programs. As a data contract, I wish to be able to return a list of variable length from one of my methods. Say, the structure I wish to return is `my_data_type`, what should I put as a contract data structure?

I can think of something like this:

```
struct data_type_list
{
    my_data_type* data_list;
    int count;
};
```

where the consumer knows there are `count` elements in the list and consumer terminates the array at `data_list[count-1]`.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how the user of your library utilizes the returned data. I would probably go with your solution if the data is pretty much read-only (in a sense that the user doesn't want to write to it but just iterates over every element pointed to by `data_type_list.data_list`). If the user wants to do extensive modifications like adding to or deleting data, a linked list would be the preferred data structure to use, I think:

```c
/* example of a node in a singly-linked list */
struct list_node {
    void *data;
    struct list_node *next;
}
```

A `NULL` pointer indicates the end of the list while data can be accessed using the `data` member of every node. You could of course add a `struct list_node *prev` member that points to the previous node, too (yielding a doubly-linked list).

Comment: It is going to be a read only data structure, as the library I am writing is dealing with making REST API calls with cURL and returning response data.

Comment: If that's the case then you probably already answered your own question. Any requirements regarding searchability/sortability of your data? The only other thing I could think of is a NULL terminated array (similar to how C represents strings) which would save the (minimal) overhead of keeping `count` in sync with the actual length of the data.